# Error when trying to acces parent folder in Electron/Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, filesystems, electron

I'm trying to check whether a path in a parent directory is a file or a directory.

My file system looks like this:

- files/

  - html/

    - index.html
  - javascript/

    - index.js
  - test/

    - test.jpg

Electron is started from the parent directory of files/.
My code in the index.js file:

```
console.log(`file://${__dirname}/../test/test.jpg`);
console.log(fs.lstatSync(`file://${__dirname}/../test/test.jpg`).isFile());
```

When I start Electron I get two messages in the log. The first one is the path of the picture I want to access (test.jpg). When I paste this path into my browser, the picture is shown, so it is the correct path.
But the second message is an error:

```
Uncaught Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, lstat
```

And then the same path in single quotation marks ('').

I used to have the index.js and the index.html file in the same path from which electron is started from (parent folder of files/) and it worked, so I guess that it has problems accesing a parent folder.
How can I solve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Node `fs` module works with file paths, not URLs, so you need to pass a valid path to `fs.lstatSync`:

```
fs.lstatSync(`${__dirname}/../test/test.jpg`).isFile()
```